Sentence meanings: You are not going to die. I can't draw the curtain for I need the light. I want to finish the painting and get some money for us."
An extract from O. Henry's The Last Leaf
Sue and Johnsy, two young artists, live together, but Johnsy falls seriously ill with pneumonia and loses the will to live.
She believes she will die when the last leaf of an ivy creeper outside their window falls.
The doctor tells Sue that Johnsy's recovery depends on her will to live, not just medicine. Sue tries everything to lift Johnsy's spirits

Johnsy did not say anything. Sue went and brought her a bowl of soup. "I don't want any soup," said Johnsy. "I am not hungry... Now there are only four leaves left. I want to see the last one fall before it gets dark. Then I will sleep forever."
Sue said, "You are not going to die. I can't draw the curtain for I need the light. I want to finish the painting and get some money for us. Please, my dear friend," she begged Johnsy, "promise not to look out of the window while I paint."

What is the sentence meaning?
I checked the meaning of  "draw the curtains"

Pull a curtain back or to one side to let in more light or to discover what is behind it.
For example, The sun was so pleasant I drew the curtains .


Ivy is evergreen - are you sure the creeper was ivy?

@KateBunting This is mentioned in the text. The lessons aren't original but abridged version to suit the learners. Some types of ivy shed their leaves in autumn, including Boston ivy:
Boston ivy: A deciduous vine that loses its leaves in autumn, and its leaves turn a brilliant shade of scarlet before falling

Actually it's 'a tree' in the original!

To draw means, in general, to pull. Thus one draws a card from the deck, and a drawer is a sort of box that can be pulled from within a piece of furniture. The command or request Draw nigh (or near) means, figuratively, “Pull yourself toward me.”
To draw the curtain means to pull it: often closed (as in Her death drew the curtain on an era now ended) but sometimes open. And since the author tells us that Sue needed the light but recognized that having it brought the risk that Johnsy might look out the window, it’s clear which of closed and open she meant.
